# Function inside Variable

Tags: php

I have this variable in class: (this works)

```
public $logFname = '_fail.log';
```

But I need this: (doesn't work)

```
public $logFname = date('d').'_fail.log';
```

Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use a function when you define a variable. You should initialize it somewhere.

You should do that like this:

```
public $logFname;

public function __construct()
{
  $this->logFname = date('d').'_fail.log';
}
```

Comment: see http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php : This declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant value

Answer (score 3):

You should first declare the variable and then define it.

```
public $logFname;
```

Then Use it like:

```
$this->logFname = date('d').'_fail.log';
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class Log {
    public $logFname = '_fail.log';

    public function __construct() {
        $this->logFname = date('d').'_fail.log';
    }
}
```

You can not use any function when you declare a variable in a class.